# Как узнать список установленных шрифтов на системе, поддерживающих кириллицу?

Tags: linux, debian, шрифты

Собственно как узнать список установленных шрифтов на системе, поддерживающих кириллицу на системе Debian (Linux)?

Comment: вопрос содержит два никак не связанных (и, насколько понимаю, весьма глобальных) вопроса: 1. как получить список всех установленных шрифтов? 2. как определить, что конкретный шрифт содержит глифы для всех символов кириллицы? (в кириллице, кстати, несколько больше 33 букв, из которых состоит алфавит современного русского языка)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала нужно понять, что кириллица - это много языков. Включая сербский и македонский. Но это не проблема. Можно для нужных языков поспрашивать

список шрифтов с поддержкой украинского языка

```
fc-list :lang=uk
```

список языков с поддержкой русского

```
fc-list :lang=ru
```